# Should I be reducing salt amounts in recipes if cooking with tap water that has passed through a salt based water softener?

Tags: salt, water

Should I be reducing salt amounts in recipes if cooking with tap water that has passed through a salt based water softener? Or is the amount of salt from the softener negligible? I'm probably over-thinking it.... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

Water softeners do not add any salt to the water. They use the sodium from the salt, not the salt itself.

This is known as an [ion-exchange process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_exchange)

If your softened water tastes at all salty, you need to check with a maintenance engineer.

In 'health' terms, there is a slightly increased sodium content, but in flavour terms there is no additional salt.

Comment: That's the on-topic answer, though there may be a little salty flavour from the resulting sodium compounds. However the kitchen tap normally bypasses any water softener because the increase in sodium consumption can be a concern for health reasons. The OP may want to review their sodium intake, especially if they drink a lot of that water

Comment: The recommendation for unsoftened kitchen taps is for houses "with babies or adults on sodium-free diets". My father-in-law is a retired softener installer/engineer. His own kitchen uses softened water. tbh, I'd never even considered it before now - I'm no expert on the subject myself.

Comment: Yea, the reason is asked the question is we were told to not water plants with it so we have a tap outside for the hose that bypasses the softener. We only cook with the water here, we drink water from those 5Gal drums you fill yourself.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think that recommendation has been stretched as a precaution for potential future users - my parents had one fitted a few years ago.  I'm also told unsoftened makes better tea but I wouldn't know, I don't drink tea - and it might depend on the tea.  Anyway not such a worry for the OP if they don't drink it - Matt, IME drinking water straight from the tap is more common here in the UK, than in the US, though I havent spent much time your side of the Atlantic.

Comment: @Matt - I've never lived anywhere you can't just drink from the tap, whether the water was soft or hard, so general 'potable water' rules would still apply.

Comment: Does your food taste salty?